# Security risk of having DOC files on a public facing SharePoint site

Tags: security, sharepoint, anonymous

I was wondering if having PDFs as opposed to DOCs would make our public facing SharePoint 2010 environment more secure. Specifically, I am talking about anonymous users accessing documents stored in Document Libraries.

I am also interested knowing best practices in general, not just SharePoint, e.g., DOC vs PDF risks on a ColdFusion box, etc.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site is only allowing downloads of files from your anonymous site, there should really be no difference from a security standpoint between a .doc and a .pdf file.  PDF files tend to be more universal and can be opened on more platforms without requiring Office or similar application that is able to open .doc files.

With your SharePoint 2010 site, if you have Office Web Apps installed on your farm, then those Word files can open in the browser without requiring a user to have an Office suite installed on their local machine.

As with any site or application, security comes down to how the application is built and how well your infrastructure has been hardened against malicious traffic.